# Django: MultiFile Upload

Tags: jquery, python, django, file-upload

I'm developing a custom Django project and I'm stuck in a simple task:

- Upload multiple files in Django

I'd like to use any of these JQuery/AJAX libraries:

- [PUpload](http://www.plupload.com/example_jquery_ui.php)
- [DropZone JS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)
- [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html)

I'm used to upload images in **Django** 1 by 1 using *Django Forms*. I create a `forms.FileField` in my form and I don't have any problems managing the file.

I've been reading about ***formsets*** because I thought that could fit my needs here but I feel I don't understand them very well

My doubts are beause with **JQuery File Upload** you can select multiple files to upload, and it's possible to start uploads files individually. You can select 7 files to upload and start uploading only the 3rd file...

- It's possible to manage this kind of uploading via Django ?
- Wich is the most secure and painless way to do/manage this ?

**I'm interested in the option of uploading multiple files, with option of managing them individually (or not) depending on the user like JQuery File Upload**

*I've already checked this stackoverflow questions:*

- *[Need multi file upload in django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772479/need-multi-file-upload-in-django-forms)*
- *[Django and ulti image upload form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851167/django-and-multi-image-upload-form)*
- *[Multiple files upload using same input name in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851336/multiple-files-upload-using-same-input-name-in-django)*

Thanks

Comment: You can integrate `JQuery File Upload` with  `inlineformset_factory`. Simply send AJAX to your CreateView and handle formset like a form (doesn't care how many forms you send)

Comment: I'm goint to try your suggestion today! Thanks for the info

Comment: Maybe I will write guide about this in a month, because faced the same problems in the current project